# Spark properties file read

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ide, intellij-eap

I tried to read a properties file in spark where my file location is     available while run the job getting below error
    code is

```
object runEmpJob {    
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("starting emp job")
    val props = ConfigFactory.load()
    val envProps = props.getConfig("C:\\Users\\mmishra092815\\IdeaProjects\\use_case_1\\src\\main\\Resource\\filepath.properties")

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.directory", "D:\\SHARED\\winutils-master\\hadoop-2.6.3\\bin")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().
         appName("emp dept operation").
         master(envProps.getString("Dev.executionMode")).
         getOrCreate()
    val empObj = new EmpOperation

    empObj.runEmpOperation(spark, "String", fileType = "csv")

    val inPutPath = args(1)
    val outPutPath = args(2)    
  }
}


getting error:
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path C:\Users\mmishra092815\IdeaProjects\use_case_1\src\main\Resource\filepath.properties':
>   Token not allowed in path expression: ':' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.PathParser.parsePathExpression(PathParser.java:155)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.PathParser.parsePathExpression(PathParser.java:74)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.PathParser.parsePath(PathParser.java:61)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Path.newPath(Path.java:230)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:192)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:268)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:274)
>   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:41) 
>   at executor.runEmpJob$.main(runEmpJob.scala:12)
>   at executor.runEmpJob.main(runEmpJob.scala)
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Loading happens in `ConfigFactory.load()`. If you want to load configuration from specific file, pass it like:

```
val props = ConfigFactory.load("C:\\Users\\mmishra092815\\IdeaProjects\\use_case_1\\src\\main\\Resource\\filepath.properties")
```

As described in [API documentation](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#getConfig-java.lang.String-), `getConfig` method does not load configuration from file - it returns a `Config` object for given [config path](https://github.com/lightbend/config#understanding-config-and-configobject) (not filesystem path!)